# Comparing a week to another past week in DAX/PQ Power BI with DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to do what may seem somewhat easy but I cannot figure out in Power BI.

I have a dataset with the following columns:

- Inventory (Numerical Column)
- WeekEnding (date column)
- Year (Numerical column)
- WeekNumber (Numerical column)
- Sales (Numerical Column)

One of the unique things about the column inventory is that it is only populated on weeks 8,16,24,32,40,52.

I want a measure to return the inventory amount for the last time inventory was done. For example, if I'm viewing week 32, I want another column named Beg_Inv to show the ending inventory for week 24.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
BegInv2 = 
CALCULATE(SUM(Production[EndingInventoryAmount]), 
FILTER(ALL(Production[Week - Numerical], Production[Year - Numerical], Production[EndingInventoryAmount]), 
Production[Week - Numerical] = SELECTEDVALUE(Production[Week - Numerical]) &&
Production[Year - Numerical] = SELECTEDVALUE(Production[Year - Numerical]) ))
```

and also:

```
Beg_Inv = 
CALCULATE(SUM(Production[EndingInventoryAmount]), 
FILTER(ALL(Production[Week - Numerical], Production[Year - Numerical], Production[EndingInventoryAmount]), DATEADD(Production[WeekEnding],-8*7, DAY)))
```

Here is a sample of my data:

[image]

Here is the text option: https://pastebin.com/aGY6BGjp

These two codes are only returning the inventory for week 32.

Any ideas anyone?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected output. Do you want this in DAX or M (power query)?

Comment: Ok let me add a sample data. DAX would be prefered. Thank you @DavidBacci

Comment: @DavidBacci updated. Does that help?

Comment: @LD-DS-00 - it would be much better if you post data as text, not image

Comment: It is unclear how you obtain your values for `Beg_Inv` for Week 24, nor why `Ending` and `Beg_Inv` are the same for all entries in Week 8. BTW this is fairly simple in PQ, if that is an option.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hey, thank you for your response. Actually, you are completely right. Week 8 is to follow the same pattern as the previous weeks. Changing the data manually, I made the mistake of not passing the values of week 52 in EndingInv to Beg_Inv in week 8. 

Values for Beg_Inv in week 24 would have come from the EndingInventory from Week 16 (not shown in this sample data). I would be open to doing it in PQ. I would appreciate the help! Thank you

PS. Tomorrow when I get to my work computer, I will change this oversight in Week 8.

Comment: @LD-DS-00 Since Bacci has posted a DAX solution, I won't bother with PQ, but unless you let me know you prefer that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld iven our conversation below, this might be better done in PQ in Power BI Service. What do you think?

Comment: I'll add a PQ solution and then you can test it. My guess is that it would be slower, but can't tell unless you try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
Beg_Inv = 
VAR currentPeriod = 'Table'[WeekEnding]
VAR lastPeriod =  CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[WeekEnding]), REMOVEFILTERS(), 'Table'[WeekEnding] < currentPeriod)
RETURN
CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[EndingInventoryAmount]),ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[DepartmentName]), 'Table'[WeekEnding] = lastPeriod )
```

Comment: Thank you DavidBacci and RonRosenfeld. The output that you posted is exactly what I want; However, I'm getting an error in this piece of code: VAR currentPeriod = 'Table'[WeekEnding]. It says that it cannot find  it cannot find name 'WeekEnding' but the variable is there! The actual error I will post down below in a separa comment. If I put minx around  'Table'[WeekEnding] I can see a result, but its not what we want.

Comment: A single value for column 'WeekEnding' in table 'Production' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Comment: Is this a calculated column or a measure? The code provided is for a calculated column with a table named "Table" and columns spelt exactly as written.

Comment: You are correct. Iswitch it from being a measure to a calculated column; however, now im getting the error: Function 'CALCULATE' is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models. 

Thank you for giving me a hand.

Comment: You didn't mention it was direct query. Direct query comes with all kinds of limitations. Have a read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new to Power BI and not super familiar with all its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Power Query.
See the code comments for suggestions and algorithm.

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"StoreNumber", Int64.Type}, {"StoreName", type text}, 
        {"DepartmentName", type text}, {"WeekEnding", type date}, 
        {"Week", Int64.Type}, {"Fiscal Year", Int64.Type}, 
        {"EndingInventoryAmount", Int64.Type}}),

/*If data not sorted as per your example
    add a sorting step here*/

//Add Index for subsequent sorting        
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//group by StoreNumber, StoreName and DepartmentName
//then add aggregation with a shifted EndingInventoryAmount column 
//which would be the Beg_Inv for that row
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"StoreNumber", "StoreName", "DepartmentName"}, {
        {"Starting", (t)=>Table.FromColumns(
                            Table.ToColumns(t)
                             & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(t[EndingInventoryAmount],1)},
                            type table [StoreNumber=nullable number, StoreName=nullable text, DepartmentName=nullable text, 
                                        WeekEnding=nullable date, Week=nullable number, Fiscal Year=nullable number, 
                                        EndingInventoryAmount=nullable number, Index=number, Beg_Inv=number])}}),

//Expand the subtables
    #"Expanded Starting" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Starting", {"WeekEnding", "Week", "Fiscal Year", "EndingInventoryAmount", "Index", "Beg_Inv"}),

//Sort back to original order
//Then remove the Index column and set the data types
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Starting",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"StoreNumber", Int64.Type}, {"StoreName", type text}, {"DepartmentName", type text}, {"WeekEnding", type date}, {"Week", Int64.Type}, {"Fiscal Year", Int64.Type}, {"EndingInventoryAmount", Int64.Type}, {"Beg_Inv", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Hi @Ron, I put your code and this is the error I get. https://pastebin.com/m2gHRmvm

Thank you for your input. Its more complicated that I expected.

Comment: @LD-DS-00 You did not include the #"Changed Type" line in your code. So if you don't need/want it in your code, you need to change the reference to it in your next line - `#"Added Index" - to refer to the proper table (`Source` in your case).

Comment: Hi @Ron, I think I corrected the code: https://pastebin.com/9BHuf6bW. Every cell in the new column shows as error. Any idea? Also, I dont think this matters, but in the dataset right now, we do not have the Beg_Inv. Thank you for your patience and for providing your knowledge!

Comment: Since you are returning the `#"Changed Type"` step at the end, but you are seeing an "extra column", it is clear that your `Production` variable is not the same as what you show in your example (from which I removed the `beg_inv` column before processing. Since you have chosen to not reveal the error, I can't really go much further. Why did you choose to return `#"Changed Type"` at the end of the query? Actually, now that I look more closely, you chose to do that in both of your code examples. Why?